# How to get fields from enum

Tags: java, enums

I have enum which looks like this example

```
public enum Animals {

   Cat("Cat", "fluffy animal"),
   Dog("Dog", "barking animal");

   private String name;
   private String description;
}

 Animals(String name, String description){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
 }

 public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

From outside class how can I get the name and description Strings ?

Comment: Is your enum missing constructor and getter?

Comment: @Jerry06 I have constructor and getters and setters I will edit my post, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just add getters for your fields:

```
public enum Animals {

    Cat("Cat", "fluffy animal"), 
    Dog("Dog", "barking animal");

    private final String name;
    private final String description;

    Animals(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

And you can access them using the getters:

```
Animals.Cat.getName();
Animals.Cat.getDescription();
```

Just a side note: please use all-uppercase identifiers for your enum values. It's also a good idea to make these fields (`name` and `description`) final.

Comment: And set the fields in a constructor.